# How to build a predictive model with multiple features?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, feature-selection, random-forest, feature-extraction

I built an R RandomForest Regression model. The source training data is a historical monthly report of all closed tickets, and the data for forecasting/prediction is a report of open tickets. These reports are generated by another team.

I test/train the model using two years of historical closed ticket data, and predict (forecast) a ŷ Completion Date for each open ticket.

The closed tickets training data looks like this:

| ID | Dollars | Fruit | Etc | StartDate | CompletionDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA088 | 500 | Apple | ... | 1/1/2020 | 2/15/2020 |
| AB100 | 1000 | Apple | ... | 1/1/2020 | 5/15/2020 |
| AB101 | 2000 | Banana | ... | 1/1/2020 | 5/15/2020 |
| BB723 | 5000 | Apple | ... | 1/5/2020 | 3/20/2020 |
| BB724 | 3000 | Lime | ... | 1/5/2020 | 3/20/2020 |
| BB725 | 1000 | Orange | ... | 1/5/2020 | 3/20/2020 |

The open ticket data looks similar, except it lacks CompletionDate, and sometimes various fields are "Unknown" at this time.

To build the model, I withhold "ID", make all categorical values factors, use CompletionDate as my y variable, and train the RandomForest on a majority of available features.

**Recently, the team that generates this data threw a curve ball, rather than each row being a single record, rows are line-items of a higher level ticket!** A majority of tickets have only one line-item, the remaining tickets can have between 2 and 6 line-items.

| ID_Parent | ID_Row | Dollars | Fruit | Etc | StartDate | CompletionDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 088 | 500 | Apple | ... | 1/1/2020 | 2/15/2020 |
| AB | 100 | 1000 | Apple | ... | 1/1/2020 | 5/15/2020 |
| AB | 101 | 2000 | Banana | ... | 1/1/2020 | 5/15/2020 |
| BB | 723 | 5000 | Apple | ... | 1/5/2020 | 3/20/2020 |
| BB | 724 | 3000 | Lime | ... | 1/5/2020 | 3/20/2020 |
| BB | 725 | 1000 | Orange | ... | 1/5/2020 | 3/20/2020 |

I have considered to summarize (rollup) records, which is easy for numeric value like Dollar (`Sum(Dollars)`). I could concatenate the multiple categorical values, however, each factor is independent and has strong predictive value to the model (i.e. line items with "Apple" has a weight / meaning that would be lost if I simply concatenated as a string with the other row's value)

| ID_Parent | SumDollars | ConcatenatedFruit | Etc | StartDate | CompletionDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 500 | Apple | ... | 1/1/2020 | 2/15/2020 |
| AB | 3000 | Apple, Banana | ... | 1/1/2020 | 5/15/2020 |
| BB | 9000 | Apple, Lime, Orange | ... | 1/5/2020 | 3/20/2020 |

How should I handle a categorical feature like Fruit that contains multiple factors?

Can RandomForest accept a feature that contains multiple factors? Do I need to use a different type of model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendations is to OneHotEncode this variable, to finally obtain something like this:

| ID_Parent | SumDollars | ConcatenatedFruit_Apple | ConcatenatedFruit_Banana | ConcatenatedFruit_Lime | ConcatenatedFruit_Orange | Etc | StartDate | CompletionDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 500 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... | 1/1/2020 | 2/15/2020 |
| AB | 3000 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | ... | 1/1/2020 | 5/15/2020 |
| AB | 9000 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | ... | 5/1/2020 | 3/20/2020 |

Moreover, if you OneHotEncoded this way, random forest can deal perfectly with this categorical feature.

Here I provide you one code that will do what I commented:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 1, 2], 'class': ['2 3', '1 3', '3 5']})
df['class'] = df['class'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' '))
df_long = df.explode('class')
df_one_hot_encoded = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df_long['class'],prefix='class', prefix_sep='_')], axis=1)
df_one_hot_encoded_compact = df_one_hot_encoded.groupby('id').max().reset_index()
```

I've extracted it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646473/how-could-i-do-one-hot-encoding-with-multiple-values-in-one-cell) (answered by *OmaymaS*)

Comment: Thank you for your advice on One-Hot encoding, I've posted an `R` solution at https://stackoverflow.com/q/73230052/10276092